# Changing Audio Pitch of "sounder"

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, audio, avfoundation

Edit: Added new code at the bottom.

I'm pretty new at coding, so I started by creating a soundboard app. I've been able to use the "rate" command to slow down or speed up the audio, but now I'm looking to change pitch too. Ideally, I'd like to have two switches. One that speeds up the audio and raises the pitch, one that slows and lowers, and if they're both off, it plays normal. Below is my code which works for everything except changing pitch. Any input is greatly appreciated. For reference, sass is slow, chip is fast.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var Sounder1 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Sounder2 = AVAudioPlayer()

let sassFloat: Float = 0.5
let myInt = Int(sassFloat)

let chipFloat: Float = 3.0
let myInt2 = Int(chipFloat)

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sassSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet weak var chipSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        Sounder1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sound1", ofType: "mp3")!))
        Sounder1.prepareToPlay()
        Sounder1.enableRate = true
    }catch{

    }

    do {
        Sounder2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sound2", ofType: "wav")!))
        Sounder2.prepareToPlay()
        Sounder2.enableRate = true
    }catch{

    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func sassAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    chipSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func chipAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    sassSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
    if sassSwitch.isOn {
        Sounder1.rate = sassFloat
        Sounder1.play()
    } else if chipSwitch.isOn {
        Sounder1.rate = chipFloat
        Sounder1.play()
    } else {
        Sounder1.rate = 1.0
        Sounder1.play()
    }

}

@IBAction func play2(_ sender: Any) {
    if sassSwitch.isOn {
        Sounder2.rate = sassFloat
        Sounder2.play()
    } else if chipSwitch.isOn {
        Sounder2.rate = chipFloat
        Sounder2.play()
    } else {
        Sounder2.rate = 1.0
        Sounder2.play()
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This is the new code I've come up with based on @ericl suggestions. I still need to `reset()` the audioEngine but I also had a few questions. 
1) Will the `if` `else if` `else` statement actually work in this situation? 
2) Where do I add the `reset()` statement. 
3) Do I need to detach the node after each sound is played? Or just reset?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sassSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var chipSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func sassAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    chipSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
}
@IBAction func chipSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    sassSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
}


///Playback Engine
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

///Player's Nodes
private let pitchPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
private let timePitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()

///Audio Files to be played
private var audioFile1 = AVAudioFile()
private var audioFile2 = AVAudioFile()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PeteNope", ofType:
        "mp3") {
        let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        setPlayerFile(filePathURL)

    }

    if let filePath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Law_WOW", ofType:
        "mp3") {
        let filePath2URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath2)

        setPlayerFile2(filePath2URL)

    }
}

private func setPlayerFile(_ fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

        self.audioFile1 = file


    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
    }
}

private func setPlayerFile2(_ fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

        self.audioFile2 = file


    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
    }
}


@IBAction func sound1Play(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sassSwitch.isOn {
        timePitch.pitch = -300
        timePitch.rate = 0.5
        audioEngine.attach(pitchPlayer)
        audioEngine.attach(timePitch)

        audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        pitchPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile1, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

        // Start the engine.
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not start engine. error: \(error).")
        }

        pitchPlayer.play()

    } else if chipSwitch.isOn {
        timePitch.pitch = +500
        timePitch.rate = 2.0
        audioEngine.attach(pitchPlayer)
        audioEngine.attach(timePitch)

        audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        pitchPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile1, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

        // Start the engine.
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not start engine. error: \(error).")
        }

        pitchPlayer.play()

    } else {
        timePitch.pitch = +0
        timePitch.rate = 1.0
        audioEngine.attach(pitchPlayer)
        audioEngine.attach(timePitch)

        audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile1.processingFormat)
        pitchPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile1, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

        // Start the engine.
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not start engine. error: \(error).")
        }
        pitchPlayer.play()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: You dont attempt to change pitch anywhere? and when you do what values are you using? in my project I set the pitch to 1000 (chipmunk mode) or -1000 (darth vadar mode).

Comment: Correct, that’s what I’m trying to set up. Basically, the two switches I have slow down or speed up the rate. I’d like to tie in the pitch changes to those switches. I might not even need the rate change once the pitch is in, but I figured I’d try for both being tied to the switches and then strip one out later if I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll use the `AVAudioEngine` to attach the `AVAudioPlayerNode` to the `AVAudioUnitTimePitch` effect. I checked Apple's [AudioUnitV3Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioUnitV3Example/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code and cobbled together a working example from it. You'll want to implement more state and error handling that you can find in there. Anyway, here goes:

Define some private variables at the top of your class:

```
   /// Playback engine.
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    /// Engine's player node.
    private let pitchPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    private let timePitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()

    /// File to play.
    private var audioFile: AVAudioFile?
```

Check for a valid audio file:

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

     if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sound1", ofType: 
 "mp3") {
         let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

         setPlayerFile(filePathURL)

         }
     }

     private func setPlayerFile(_ fileURL: URL) {
         do {
             let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

             self.audioFile = file


         } catch {
             fatalError("Could not create AVAudioFile instance. error: \(error).")
         }
     }

     @IBAction func verySlowPlayback(sender: UIButton) {


    timePitch.pitch = -300
    timePitch.rate = 0.5
    audioEngine.attach(pitchPlayer)
    audioEngine.attach(timePitch)

    audioEngine.connect(pitchPlayer, to: timePitch, format: audioFile?.processingFormat)
    audioEngine.connect(timePitch, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile?.processingFormat)
    pitchPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile!, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

    // Start the engine.
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not start engine. error: \(error).")
    }

    pitchPlayer.play()

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It will help me get started later when I can get in front of the computer. Do you have any suggestions on how I would tie those to a switch though, instead of a button? Basically I want two switches, one for fast and high pitched and one for slow and low. I’d like to have multiple buttons with sounds played normally, but if a switch is enabled it either speeds or slows it.

Comment: As an aside: I edited the post to add the `rate` property to the `AVAudioUnitTimePitch`  class: `timePitch.rate = 0.5` .

Comment: You can have `play1()` and `play2()`  switches altering `AVAudioUnitTimePitch` properties.  You'll see if you need to `reset()` the audio engine or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @ericl. I edited the post with some new code I threw together with your edits. If you get a chance, just take a look at it and let me know if it makes any sense or if I'm way off base.

Comment: I think you should create a simpler test project with one file and one switch and get that to work. Take a look at that Apple sample code for a trip down the rabbit hole and consider using a boolean like `isPlaying' to check for state. Figure out your next Minimal Complete & Verifiable Example for another question and you'll probably find answers along the way! (I'm a beginner, too; see my low point score?) Anyway, I did answer your original question "how to change pitch" so please accept my answer!

Comment: Yep. I appreciate your help. I have checked it as answered. Thank you again.